# What is the procedure when a spacesuit gets a tear in it?

Tags: atmosphere, spacesuits, emergency

What do you do if you are in space and you get a rip in your spacesuit other than getting right with God? What if you cannot get back to base in time?

Comment: My answer to the suggested duplicate shows the procedural flow through the checklist for a leak during EVA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organic Marble's [answer to this QA](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/what-first-aid-options-do-astronauts-have-during-an-eva?noredirect=1&lq=1) describes the steps taken if a leak is suspected. Once it's definite that there's a leak, the outcome would depend largely on how large a hole is in the suit, but the procedure is likely the same: immediately cancel the EVA operation, have crew member "A" in the compromised suit head immediately for the nearest usable airlock, and have a crew member "B" whose suit is intact head immediately for crew member "A" to make sure they reach the airlock.

[A small hole of ~3mm or less diameter would leak slowly enough to be survivable.](https://www.quora.com/How-are-astronauts-trained-to-handle-a-suit-breach-in-vacuum-Can-they-be-repaired-outside-the-station-Do-they-take-some-kind-of-emergency-sealant-out-with-them)

Without air in the suit, an astronaut will lose consciousness in no more than about 10-15 seconds; death will follow within a minute. [This QA suggests that it takes at least 10 minutes to repressurize the airlocks on ISS](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5010/195), which means an astronaut who can't reach the airlock under her own power will likely not survive.

EVAs from ISS are normally conducted by two crew members for safety; [it seems only one 3-person EVA has been conducted to date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extravehicular_activity#Capability_milestones).

Comment: Space suits used for EVA consist of multiple layers. The upper layers protect against micrometeroites and the heat caused by the Sun's radiation. If there is a tear or hole within these upper layers, the suit would not loose pressure.